# Append sub record in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, nosql

This is my db

```
db.table_name( {
_id: “object_id()”,
user_id: <user_name>,
playlist:
    {
        types:  "show",
        video_url: “video source url”,
        thumb_url: “thumb url”,
        title: “video title”,
        created_date: “new date()”
    }
});
```

Now, the table states that, there is a user, having playlist field, now i want that when I insert record for first time, insertion should be done like this:

```
_id: objectid12345,
user_id: 1,
playlist:
    {
        types:  "show",
        video_url: “video source url”,
        thumb_url: “thumb url”,
        title: “video title”,
        created_date: “new date()”
    }
});
```

now, when I insert the record for the second time, for the same user, it should first check, whether data for the same user exist?

1.if yes then,data should be inserted like this:

```
_id: objectid12345,
user_id: 1,
playlist:
    {
        types:  "show",
        video_url: “video source url”,
        thumb_url: “thumb url”,
        title: “video title”,
        created_date: “new date()”
    },
playlist:
    {
        types:  "show",
        video_url: “video source url”,
        thumb_url: “thumb url”,
        title: “video title”,
        created_date: “new date()”
    }

});
```

Similarly when I do next insertion for the same user, then insertion should be done like this:

```
_id: objectid12345,
user_id: 1,
playlist:
    {
        types:  "show",
        video_url: “video source url”,
        thumb_url: “thumb url”,
        title: “video title”,
        created_date: “new date()”
    },
playlist:
    {
        types:  "show",
        video_url: “video source url”,
        thumb_url: “thumb url”,
        title: “video title”,
        created_date: “new date()”
    },
playlist:
    {
        types:  "show",
        video_url: “video source url”,
        thumb_url: “thumb url”,
        title: “video title”,
        created_date: “new date()”
    }

});
```

That is, playlist record should be appended for the same user.

1. If record does not exist for the same user, then the record should be inserted as we insert record for the first time.

Now, I dont know how to above stuff using mongoose
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First off, playlist should be an array of objects, so you'd have:

```
playlists : [
  {
    types:  "show",
    video_url: “video source url”,
    thumb_url: “thumb url”,
    title: “video title”,
    created_date: “new date()”
  },
  {
    types:  "show",
    video_url: “video source url”,
    thumb_url: “thumb url”,
    title: “video title”,
    created_date: “new date()”
  },
  {
    types:  "show",
    video_url: “video source url”,
    thumb_url: “thumb url”,
    title: “video title”,
    created_date: “new date()”
  }
]
```

You'd also want to define it as a nested schema, along the lines of:

```
var playlistSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  type: String,
  video_url: String
});
```

Then reference it in your user schema, for example:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ser_id: String
  playlists: [playlistSchema]
});
```

When you create a new playlist for a user Mongoose will automatically give it a unique `_id` that you can use to access it.

For checking if a given user exists before adding a playlist - your application code should really do this, and create a user as a separate operation.

Answer (score 0):

As Simon you need to have playlists as an array of playlist schema. After you are done with that you need to read two documents:

Modifying documents - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/modify-documents/
and Array Update operators - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update-array/